# Not a personal finance question, question

Tags: discussion, questions

[I made a statement](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4182) (let's call it that) about VAT. It was closed because it's not a personal finance question. So, my question here is if anybody knows where I should pose these kind of theories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These types of questions are probably more suited for an economics site. If you are interested in such questions, you may want to consider supporting this proposal:

[**Area 51: Economics**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics)